# Tortoisesvn not allowing any SVN operations on a repository

Tags: ssh, tortoisesvn

I have TortoiseSVN 1.6.17 64 bit installed on a Windows 7 machine.  I am also running subversion under Cygwin and that is the SSH client tortoise is configured to use.  I am able to perform SVN operations from the Cygwin command line (e.g. commit, log) and everything seems normal there.

Attempts to update, log, commit, etc. fail when I try to use tortoise with the error...

> Commit failed (details follow):
>   To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the 
>   [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
>   Network connection closed unexpectedly

I have tried to remove the `-q` option from the ssh command everywhere I can find it (my .subversion folder, cygwin/etc, the Settings of tortoise) but I can't seem to get any more information about what the problem is.  The behavior is the same for all checked out folders on this machine.  I also can't check out anything.  Tortoise works fine with the remote repository on other machines.

I've tried to uninstall/re-install tortoise, but because it remembers history I assume some things were left behind somewhere.  The previous version was an older 32 bit build.  Something seems to be busted in the authentication process, but I haven't a clue what it might be.  I've tried removing the repository from the cache settings and removing the remote machine from the known_hosts file in my .ssh folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've been battling this - and getting the same error or else:

> Unable to open connection to svn. Host does not exist

I finally solved it:

Go to the Tortoise settings (can be found under Start, Program Files, etc - or run `"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:settings`)

On the network tab, the bottom section is labeled `SSH client`. Mine was set to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe"`

Set the SSH client to `"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe"` or wherever your *TortoisePlink.exe* is hiding.

Suddenly everything works.

Answer (score 0):

1. SVN (client or server) is not, never was and can't be SSH-client
2. "Subversion configuration file", mentioned in error-message and used by TortoiseSVN (and other *native Windows* Subversion clients) is %APPDATA%\config
3. **Read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html)!**

Comment: 1. makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: 2. I've deleted that and deleted stuff from the registry to completely uninstall tortoise.  The problem remains.  svn works fine from the command line and from a cygwin shell.  It's a tortoise problem and only occurs on one win 7 computer three others are fine with the same install.

Comment: @user2291638 - try to use in TSVN TortoisePlink (part of TortpoiseSVN bundle) as SSH-client